# Excel VBA - How to click on cells In a range inside a macro and populate another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a form that, based on a number of values, if one of those values is entered into the D column, the corresponding F column will turn red. Once the F column turns red, the user is able to click on the red colored cell and it will navigate them to the macro associated with that value.

**Example**: If cell D10 = "20PART", cell F10 will turn red (*to let the user know they need to click on the cell to complete the form*) and when the user clicks on cell F10 it will take them to the macro gotoref6 (this is the macro assoc. with the value 20PART). Once the user is taken to the correct macro (after clicking cell F10),I would like the user to be able to **double-click** any value in the A column inside the macro and the value the user double-clicks to populate the red F10 cell and for the color of cell F10 to go back to white, now just displaying the value the user has selected rather than being blank and red. **Note:** The values being entered in column D are derived from a larger value in column C. All cells in column D are formatted like: '=MID(cell,16,6)'

The issues I am having now is that I am able to navigate to the macros but, I can not double-click on a value in the A column inside the macros and it doesn't navigate back to the red colored F cell in the original form. Also, for some reason, I have to click inside the D column for the cell in the F column to turn red, rather than just automatically turning red. ANY help on this would be amazing. Thanks so much. If you need more elaboration or explaining, I'd be happy to do so. Thanks again!

```
     Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7:D446")) Is Nothing Then
          Dim c As Range
          Set c = Range("D7:D446")
          For Each c In Target
              Select Case c.Value
                  Case "1000GP", "1000MM", "19FEST", "20IEDU", "20PART", "20PRDV", "20SPPR", "22DANC", "22LFLC", "22MEDA", "530CCH", "60POUBL", "74GA01", "74GA17", "74GA99", "78REDV"
                      Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                  Case Else
                     Cells(c.Row, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
              End Select
          Next c
     End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionCHange(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
          Cancel = True
          Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
            Case "1000GP": gotoref1
            Case "1000MM": gotoref2
            Case "19FEST": gotoref3
            Case "20IEDU": gotoref4
            Case "20ONLC": gotoref5
            Case "20PART": gotoref6
            Case "20PRDV": gotoref7
            Case "20SPPR": gotoref8
            Case "22DANC": gotoref9
            Case "22LFLC": gotoref10
            Case "22MEDA": gotoref11
            Case "530CCH": gotoref12
            Case "60PUBL": gotoref13
            Case "74GA01": gotoref14
            Case "74GA17": gotoref15
            Case "74GA99": gotoref16
            Case "78REDV": gotoref17
          End Select
      End If
    End Sub



   Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)'This sub will attempt to perform the double click in gotoref# macro's and populate the F column in the original form and change the color back to white background.        
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then ' the Range the user will click in the gotoref# macros will be column A    
    Cancel = True
    Call Back_to_JE 'A different macro I created to navigate user back to main form
    ActiveCell.Value = Range("F:F").Select  ' I want the value the user clicked on in the gotoref# macros to populate the corresponding F column in original form
    ActiveCellInterior.ColorIndex = 0 'I want the color of the F cell to go back to white bckgrnd when a value is present in the cell.       
    End If
    End Sub




 **'I have also Tried this approach after the Worksheet_SelectionChange() event:**

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
          Cancel = True
          Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
            Case "1000GP": gotoref1
            Case "1000MM": gotoref2
            Case "19FEST": gotoref3
            Case "20IEDU": gotoref4
            Case "20ONLC": gotoref5
            Case "20PART": gotoref6
            Case "20PRDV": gotoref7
            Case "20SPPR": gotoref8
            Case "22DANC": gotoref9
            Case "22LFLC": gotoref10
            Case "22MEDA": gotoref11
            Case "530CCH": gotoref12
            Case "60PUBL": gotoref13
            Case "74GA01": gotoref14
            Case "74GA17": gotoref15
            Case "74GA99": gotoref16
            Case "78REDV": gotoref17
          End Select
      End If
 If Target.Column = 1 And Target.ActiveCell Then
    Cancel = True  
    Call Back_to_JE 'A different macro I have which brings the user back to the main form
    ActiveCell.Value = Range("F:F").Select  ' I want the value the user clicked on in the gotoref# macors to populate the corresponding F column in original macro        
    ActiveCellInterior.ColorIndex = 0 'I want the color of the F cell to go back to white bckgrnd when a value is present in the cell.        
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any code for the double-click event?

Comment: @SJR right, I'm unsure of how to appropriately write the syntax, as well as the logic behind the double-click event. That is the main emphasis of my question.

Comment: Can you clarify precisely where your difficulty lies? You seem to have a grasp of VBA and events. Have you tried anything - if so, post that too.

Comment: @SJR I haven't tried creating a double-click event. I"ll try it now. Would that event be Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick?

Comment: Hi @A.S.H, When you say I need 'to extend it for the case the double-clicked column is A' would that adjustment be at the ` If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
    Cancel = True`? Changing the Target.Column to 1?

Comment: @A.S.H the only reason why I haven't accepted that answer is because I haven't gotten that piece of functionality to work yet. I believe you when you say that is what I need to accomplish what I what, I just haven't gotten the results yet so, I will try what you just suggested. Thanks for you're help. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Cancel = True
      Select Case Target.Offset(0, -2).Value2
        Case "1000GP": gotoref1
        Case "1000MM": gotoref2
        etc

      End Select
  End If
  If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Select Case Target.Offset(0, 1).Value2
    Case " ": Back_to_JE ' this is a macro that navigates back to the original form
  End Select
  End If
   
End Sub`

Comment: I've tried to add a second If statement under the End If. I'm trying to get the functionality to match: if the user double clicks on a value in column A in ANY macro, that value will populate the red colored F cell back on the original form. I struggle with the VBA logic and syntax, mostly.

Comment: I've actually adjusted it to be: `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = True
  With Target
    .Value = .Offset(0, -6).Value
  End With
End Sub`

Comment: Andrew can you add the code to your original post so it's properly formatted please?

Comment: @SJR Absolutely. I will do that from now on as I'm sure its easier on the eyes. I have edited my question code to match the code I have now. I have posted two version of my final beforeDoucleClick event in case one would be better than the other. Thanks so much

Comment: In your Double Click code you are referring to the active cell but that will be the cell that has been double clicked. If you want it to refer to a cell referenced in another procedure you will need to declare a public variable and set it in the relevant gotoref macro and reference that in the double click event. it might be that you need this variable to refer to Target in the SelectionChange event but I don't think I understand enough about your project to be fully confident.